# MATLAB speeding up open command

Tags: matlab

I used profile to check my code for speeding up
90% of my code is going on for

```
open('filename.mat')
```

I am looking for ways to speed it up
all the files are .mat with around 40K lines on 13 columns 
I was wondering if you know a way to speed it up, maybe changing it to

```
load('filename.mat')
```

Is there a speed difference between them?

Comment: Check [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/40111-reading-and-writing-faster-a-mat-file) out. First hit on Google. In short, using the option `'-v6'` when saving mat-files increases the speed of reading them

Comment: You might also want to check what's going on in your `%TEMP%` folder, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16413252/1714410) that might be related.

Comment: are you using linux or windows machine?

Comment: running on both, the profiler was done for windows

Comment: Is it possible that the files are not stored locally, but in a network drive? if you need to go through net to get to files it can take very long.

Comment: one more thing, try and give absolute paths to filenames so Matlab will not need to resolve paths.

Answer (score 2):

`open` has to determine the file type - if it determines it to be a `.mat` file it will call `load`.

I wouldn't have expected it to take very long to do that though...

Are you loading files over a network?

Are you running out of RAM?

To answer your question I would expect changing to load to speed things up but not by a lot...  Try it and see! :)

Comment: nice to know, i have tried it and there is not a big difference